# Is every coset of a group closed under taking inverses?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

> Is every coset of a group closed under taking inverses?

What I mean is that if $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup, and let $a$ be any element of $G$. Then the coset $aH$ is not necessary a group. But does every element of $aH$ have an inverse element also in $aH$?

Comment: No, just take the coset $\{1\}$ of $\{0\}$ in $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ for $n\ge 3$. In general, for a group $G$ and subgroup $H$, one has (exercise): every left coset $gH$ is closed under inversion iff $H$ is normal and $G/H$ is an elementary $2$-group.

Answer (score 9):

No, this does not have to hold.

Example: The symmetric group $S_3$ with 6 elements.

$U=\{\operatorname{id}, (12)\}$ is a subgroup.

Now view $(13)U=\{(13), (123)\}$. Then the element $(123)$ has no inverse.

We have $(123)(13)=(23)$ and $(123)(123)=(132)$

Answer (score 6):

No.  $a\in aH$. But if $a^{-1}\in aH$, then $a^{-1}=ah\implies h=a^{-2}$.  So $a^2\in H$.

So, for instance, consider the dihedral group, $D_4=\langle r,s\mid r^4,s^2, (rs)^2\rangle $.

Take  $H\le D_4$ where $H=\{s,e\}$.  Then $r^2\not\in H$.

Comment: Indeed, $a^{-1} \in aH$ iff $a^2 \in H$.